# How do I Map an Input Column to Multiple Output Columns in SSDT?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

How do I map an input column to multiple output columns in SSDT?
I have a Source Assistant and a Destination Assistant and when I map the columns, I am not able to select a certain input column to be mapped to multiple destination columns.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way is to make a Derived Column to copy that column with other names and map those to the desired target columns. I'm not aware of any native functionality to map one column to may target columns.